# How to detect a tap on a WKInterfaceGroup added within a table row controller?

Tags: watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacegroup, wktapgesturerecognizer

So this is my `InterfaceController` hierarchy:

```
-> InterfaceController
      -> Table
            -> RowController
                  -> Group A
                        -> Group B
                              -> Gesture
```

I've also implemented `override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {...}` of `WKInterfaceTable` where I'm receiving the selection of a row controller. However, I'm not receiving the touch event (a tap event) on Group B.

I've attached an `IBAction` with the tap gesture which should get call when I taps on the Groupp B. if I tap outside (means, on Group A) then it should call the table's `didSelectRowAt:` method but right now, it's not calling gesture's action.

Any other solution to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Temporary* I've implemented this by replacing `Group B` with a `WKInterfaceButton`. So now, I can detect the button touch as well as table's `didSelectRowAt:`. I will wait for a perfect solution to this problem.

Comment: I have a somehow similar question ; but I want to detect a double tap in group B, so the button trick will probably not make it completely

Comment: If you're not using it inside the `TableRowController` then you can directly have double tap gesture.

Comment: Thanks. Not using what ? Do you mean that if the IBAction is not in TableRowController, I can add a gesture on the group ?. So far, I used the solution of the button with a group inside. That works well enough, even if I loose the double tap detection.

Comment: Not using a group inside the `TableRowController`.